# What is the best strategy to staying alive?

Tags: super-crate-box

I've been playing a lot of this game lately and I've tried many things to keep alive while trying to get crates. I've tried spamming mines, but I never manage to have more than 4 at once. My only tactic is to get as many crates as I can while shooting anything that gets in my way. While this works for the first few crates, I find myself overrun with enemies or accidentally jumping into them.

Any ways to stay alive while collecting crates?

Answer (score 4):

Basically: kill stuff, grab crates, don't die. This game is extremely simple.

Don't let enemies get to the bottom of the screen. Stay away from the top. Never run under the hole they come from. Clear the screen a little before moving on when you get a powerful weapon.

That's all there is to the game.

Answer (score -1):

Go slowly. Don't rush.
Take them out and move on if you think it's safe.
If it gets hard, fall back.